# Tabs without icon

Tags: android, layout, tabs, icons

I'm having a look at the "Tab Layout" tutorial which is perfectly clear and my question is very simple : is it possible to create tabs with no icon, just a single title?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> > is it possible to create tabs with no icon, just a single title?

Yes. If you are doing something like:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_name").setIndicator("Some tab",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
```

Change it to:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_name").setIndicator("Some tab").setContent(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are reading [Tab layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)
There you can see that they use following function to set title and icon:

> setIndicator("Albums",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))

Same function has another version, which does not take drawable as parameter

> .setIndicator("Albums")

So, this second version of the function creates tab without icon.
Simple answer - yes, you can create tabs with title only.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a fixed height of the tabwidged.

In the Code:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height=n;
```

Or in the XML:
..

```
android:layout_height="n"
```

.. 
(with `android:gravity` you can affect where ur tabwidget gets cut)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TabSpec.setIndicator(View view)` method to customize your indicator, this method was introduced since API level 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
 TabSpec laboratorySpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Laboratory");
 laboratorySpec.setIndicator("Laboratory");
 Intent laboratoryIntent = new Intent(this, LaboratoryActivity.class);
 laboratorySpec.setContent(laboratoryIntent);
```

worked for me